# Vaadin @Tag annotation

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10

I have a question with vaadin **@Tag** annotation. When i use in my component like this **@Tag("main-page")** Edge and FF getting unexpected class names.

```
@Tag("main-page")
@HtmlImport("src/page/home.html")
@Viewport("width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no")
public class HomeView extends PolymerTemplate<HomeView.Model> implements RouterLayout, HasUrlParameter<String>,
```

And result on FF and Edge:

[image: Unexpected class name]

But in chrome, safari, opera:

[image: Its good]

Any explanation ? What did i do wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you see happens because current versions of Edge and Firefox do not natively support [Shadow DOM](https://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdomv1). You can see this by the absence of the special `#shadow-root` node in the DOM tree.

Instead of native support, Vaadin is using a polyfill that emulates most parts of the functionality. This polyfill still has some visible side effects, such as some additional CSS classes that are used for emulating the style encapsulation functionality.

This is in no way specific to the `@Tag` annotation or even Vaadin in general, but rather something that comes from the ecosystem (e.g. `extends Polymer.Element` that you would have in your `home.html` file).